# Reading .NET Fx app.config in an Azure Function v2 (.NET Core) app

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I am developing a new Azure Function using the v2 SDK. So the function app is a .NET Core App. A lot of the logic that the function needs exists in .NET Framework 4.7.2 libraries, which are referenced from the Function project.

The project compiles and runs (locally, thus far). However, even though I have an app.config file in the project, which is set to the copy to the output directory, the libraries can't seem to find the config.

The app.config file gets copied to the \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0 folder with the name app.config. That probably wouldn't work, but even when I copy the config file to the bin subfolder (\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\bin) and change it's name to myassembly.dll.config (where myassembly is the compiled function app), the config can't be found.

I've also added the connection string (one of the key configuration pieces) to local.settings.json as such

```
{
  ...,
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "connstringname": "connectionstring..."
  }
}
```

That also does not make the connection string available to the code in the .NET Framework class libraries.

I've also tried adding the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager NuGet package (4.6.0) to the Function app project, without a change.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any other easy solution. But there is a workaround.

You may add all the configurations to the local.settings.json, and the function will set all those configurations as system environments settings.

Then you can get one by:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("{key_name}");
```